# iPhone 5 locked to Japanese network KDDI

Tags: unlock

Hope someone can help me with my locked iPhone 5.
I was given it second hand in Japan and want to use it in New Zealand. 
It used to be on KDDI.

When a Sim from NZ is inserted it shows invalid Sim.

I tried an R-Sim 9+ but no success.

How can I unlock this phone?

Also is there a difference between network and carrier? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact your new carrier & see if they will unlock it. If the phone is legitimate, not stolen, doesn't have a blocked IMEI etc...

I can't say for NZ & it appears every carrier treats it differently, but here's a guide on UK networks & how they deal with it - might at least prepare you for the long conversation you might need with your own carrier.
http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-unlock-your-iphone-3501427/

There is an alternative of getting some backstreet phone shop to do it for you - but they tend to make you think it's illegal & you pay accordingly for their 'expert' advice & 'confidential service'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the phone is legal. The original carrier KDDI in Japan refusses to unlock it as do my network here in NZ.

Comment: Is there anyway I could do myself what these shops and online services claim to do?

Comment: hmm... I have no idea how the actual unlock process works, except to ring up & ask; I've never done it any other way - might be back-street phone shop time...

Comment: @Ben is there only one carrier in NZ? That would be reason enough to say goodbye to them and change carrier…

Answer (score 0):

There are some variants of unlocking iPhone. https://macback.us/tutorials/how-to-unlock-iphone-5-5s/ If original carrier refuses to do so (though it wouls be the most reliable way of doing this), so you have to either find “phone unlock guy” or try the software that allow you to do this. But both variants are risky, as you never can predict the results.